# How to upload a Excel sheet to Azure ADLS by using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, azure, azure-blob-storage

I've got a VBA code that is focused on standardized a data set and once the transformation is finished I need tu upload this Excel Sheet to a specific ADLS (csv format), so I'll be able to execute an automation in Data Factory. I've been looking for some of guidance but unfortunately I've not been lucky and I don't know where to start.

Down below is the code (is so simple, the code just select the worksheet and delete some columns):

```
Sub Delete_Columns()

    Dim k As Integer

    Worksheets("File").Select
    For k = 1 To 4
    Columns(k + 1).Delete
    Next k

End Sub
```

Could you give me a hand with this? What is necessary to add in my code to get the goal? Do I need Blob SAS Token and how can I to specify the path?

Comment: Your code deletes columns 2,4,6,8 is that what you wanted ? If not use `Worksheets(1).Columns("B:E").Delete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to upload an Excel sheet to Azure ADLS by using VBA?

You can use the code below to delete the columns and upload an Excel sheet to the ADLS account using VBA.

In the Visual Basic Editor, go to Insert > Module to create a new module. Copy and paste the code into the new module.

**Code:**

```
Sub Delete_Columns_And_Upload()

    Dim k As Integer
    Dim CSVFilePath As String
    Dim BlobServiceURL As String
    Dim ContainerName As String
    Dim BlobName As String
    Dim SAS_Token As String
    Dim HTTPReq As Object

    Worksheets("File").Select
    For k = 1 To 4
        Columns(k + 1).Delete
    Next k

    ' Specify the local path where you want to save the CSV temporarily
    CSVFilePath = "C:\Users\xxxx\test.csv"

    ' Save the modified sheet as CSV
    ActiveSheet.SaveAs CSVFilePath, xlCSV

    ' Define your Azure ADLS Storage URL
    BlobServiceURL = "https://yourstorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/"
    ContainerName = "test"
    BlobName = "example.csv"

    ' Specify your SAS Token here (including the leading '?')
    SAS_Token = "?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=co&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-09-20T13:57:47Z&st=2023-09-20T05:57:47Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxx"

    ' Combine the URL components
    Dim UploadURL As String
    UploadURL = BlobServiceURL & ContainerName & "/" & BlobName & SAS_Token

    ' Create an HTTP request object
    Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

    ' Read the CSV file data
    Dim FileData As String
    Open CSVFilePath For Binary As #1
    FileData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , FileData
    Close #1

    ' Send a PUT request to upload the file to Azure Blob Storage
    HTTPReq.Open "PUT", UploadURL, False
    HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"
    HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "x-ms-blob-type", "BLockblob"
    HTTPReq.send FileData

End Sub
```

**Console:**

[image]

Now, open your Macros dialogue box and select **`Delete_Columns_And_Upload`** macro and click **`Run`** to run the code.

**Output:**

The above executed and uploaded the Excel file to the Azure ADLS using VBA.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Venkatesan, just a quick question. How can I to create HTTPReq? How did you defined it?

Comment: The code is not working since i'm not sure HTTPReq i'm using is the proper (MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0) and for one reason when I executed the VBA code my ADLS sends me an error called "TooManyRequests"

Comment: Have you tried with `Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")` which is the latest version.

Comment: Make sure you are passing the correct sas token and you can get `SAS token` from here https://i.stack.imgur.com/avc7Z.png